# Spring mvc - @sessionattributes vs @Scope("session") beans which to use?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, session

I'm not fully understanding when to use `@SessionAttributes` vs `@Scope("session")` beans.

Currently, I'm doing the following

```
@ControllerAdvice(assignableTypes = {DashboardController.class, FindingWholeSalersController.class})
public class AuthControllerAdvice {

private IFindWholeSalerService service;

    public IFindWholeSalerService getService() {
        return service;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setService(IFindWholeSalerService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    //put firstname in session etc..
    @ModelAttribute
    public void addWholesalerDiscoveryCountToSession(Model model, Principal principal){
        if (!model.containsAttribute("firstname")) {
            String firstname = service
                    .findUserFirstName(principal.getName());
            model.addAttribute("firstname",
                    firstname);
        }
    }
```

Notice this if test `if (!model.containsAttribute("firstname"))`
Basically, if the session attribute is already in the model, then I dont want to ask my service layer to make a database request.  However, every `@RequestMapping` call in any of the controllers I'm advising, first makes a call to

```
@ModelAttribute
public void addWholesalerDiscoveryCountToSession(Model model, Principal principal)
```

Does the if test, and moves on its marry way.

Is this the right solution for keeping data in the session so you dont have to call your database, OR would `@Scope("session")` beans be a better choice OR something else?

Thanks for all advice in advance!

Comment: First of all `@SessionAttributes` isn't intended for that it is intended to store objects for the same controller in the session in between requests. It isn't intended to store long lived data in there. You already have a `Principal` so why aren't you just properly integrating your security solution with the http spec, that way the `Principal` would contain everything you need. If you use Spring Security you would already have this in place.

Comment: You could use Cache for this. Session is user specific and Cache is general.

Comment: So do you mean that I should extend UserDetails Object to my own User?  Currently, my spring security setup is using queries instead of returning a UserDetails object:

Comment: protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
   throws Exception {
  auth.jdbcAuthentication()
    .dataSource(dataSource)
    .usersByUsernameQuery(
      "SELECT username, password, enabled FROM user WHERE username=?")
    .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
      "SELECT username,role FROM user WHERE username=?");
 }